# Like (wildcard) clause in fileexporter beans.xml

Tags: data-export

I am using file exporter to export attachments starting with the name "TAC_MD_"

In the file exporter beans.xml if give name like 'TAC_DM_%' in the whereclause as shown below

ENTITY whereClause " Name like 'TAC_DM_%' "

I am getting the error "The system cannot find the file CSVs\Attachment.Name.csv"

but if i give the complete name then it works like below:

ENTITY whereClause " Name ='TAC_DM_test.msg' "

Can  anyone let me know how to use the "like" (wildcard) in the whereclause in fileexporter.

Comment: Below is the error in file exporter log file:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from file [C:\Softwares\FileExporter\process-conf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '%' in the parameter entity reference.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '%' in the parameter entity reference.

Comment: Is this related to exacttarget? If so, you should edit it to include that as a tag so experts on ET can find it easier.